# Warning in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, logcat

I am getting weird log in logcat as :

```
W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
```

How to solve it ? I think its a render time log for my this widget : **SupportMapFragment**

Comment: okay tnx bro. i think solution is still pending. lets wait for proper solution.

Comment: I think it was reported in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10201) and the solution given that it will be fixed in an upcoming release of Google Play Services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a known bug which is rendered by google-maps library. To be resolved in the next version

Comment: @Naitik this is an answer, and a valid one. The question is posted at the top.